# MSBUILD of web project with typescript throws lots of JQuery related errors

Tags: typescript, msbuild

I have a .net core 3.1 (netcoreapp3.1) razor pages project that consists of typescript files (and a few javascript files). From Visual Studio 2019 (professional) the project builds perfectly. From the command line the project builds perfectly using MSBuild.

However when I try and build from a "deployment" folder where I've "checked out" the project from source control I get a lot of typescript errors. They look like the following:

```
error TS2315: Build:Type 'JQuery' is not generic.
error TS2702: Build:'JQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
error TS2339: Build:Property 'css' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

(note: only 1 of the last, the other two are about equally split)

It sure looks like the jquery typing files are not being picked up. They are specified in the .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="jqueryui.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="3.9.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

My tsconfig.json looks pretty normal too:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "../Source"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Edit: So I grabbed a copy of the entire solution from source control into a clean directory. Did a nuget restore, dotnet restore and a msbuild /t:restore. MSBuild still fails with the same set of errors. Opened the solution in VS2019 and tried to build from there... bam the errors.

So now I have one solution that build the project correctly and one solution that doesn't. Grrrrrrrr

I'm at a loss as to what to look.

Any suggestions as to what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Success.

The underlying problem was that there was a node_modules\typings (types?) folder above the project folder (part of the solution directory). This folder was not part of the source control so it was not present in the clean locations.

There was also a set of typings in "scripts\typings" (types?). These were probably really old.

The fix was to:

1. get rid of the extraneous typings
2. add a libman.json file containing the typings needed (right click on "wwwroot" and select "add -> client-side library"):

```
    {
      "version": "1.0",
      "defaultProvider": "unpkg",
      "libraries": [
        {
          "library": "@types/jquery@3.5.0",
          "destination": "wwwroot/types/jquery/"
        },
        {
          "library": "@types/sizzle@2.3.2",
          "destination": "wwwroot/types/sizzle/"
        },
        {
          "library": "@types/jqueryui@1.12.2",
          "destination": "wwwroot/types/jqueryui/"
        }
      ]
    }
```

3. use an explicit typings element in tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "skipLibCheck": false,
        "outDir": "../Source",
        "typeRoots": [ "./types" ]
      },
      "exclude": [
      ]
    }
```

The moral of the story... Typescript compiler from Nuget GOOD. Type definitions from Nuget BAD. Relying on Visual Studio's default for typeRoots BAD.